# How to combine AND and OR clause using @Query in Spring-Data-MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to create a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM webHookDelivery 
        WHERE companyType = 'SPONSOR'
        AND companyId = 6710890
        AND eventType = 'CustodyResponseItemEvent'
        AND delivered = false
        AND (requestPayload.sponsorGovernmentId = '1234' OR requestPayload.invoiceNumber = '82899') 
        ORDER BY createdAt DESC
```

With Spring-Data-MongoDB @Query annotation, but doesn't work and also the parameters are optional.

I've tried a lot of different queries, the last one is this:

```
@Query(value = "{ 'companyType': ?0, 'companyId': ?1, 'eventType': ?2, 'delivered': ?3, '$or':[ {'requestPayload.sponsorGovernmentId': ?4}, {'requestPayload.invoiceNumber': ?5} ]}")
```

If I pass an incorrect sponsorGovernmentId and a correct invoiceNumber, the query should give me the results.

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java and SpringBoot. 
There is no need of the "'" single quotes around variables in the query, if you add them it gives error while executing query.  It should be simply ->

```
@Query(value = "{ companyType: ?0, companyId: ?1, eventType: ?2, delivered: ?3, $or:[ {requestPayload.sponsorGovernmentId: ?4}, {requestPayload.invoiceNumber: ?5} ]}")
```